# WAV file header for A-Law and mu-law

Tags: audio, header, wave, wav

Can some one tell me the WAV file header information for A-Law and Mu-Law?

Comment: You could search... google is your friend

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, the [WAVE format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAV) is a [RIFF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Interchange_File_Format) specification for mutlimedia files, which uses "chunks" to store data. Similar to a [type-length-value representation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type-length-value), each chunk contains information about its own type and length (the fields `SubChunkID` and `SubChunkSize`) before the rest of the data.The information about the audio compression is stored in the "fmt" chunk.

Read [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20130510081513/https://ccrma.stanford.edu/courses/422/projects/WaveFormat/) and [this](http://unusedino.de/ec64/technical/formats/wav.html) for more information.

Comment: The interesting - not answered - question would be what to expect at offset 20 (`0x14` and `0x15` 2 bytes) as AudioFormat. Obviously PCM = 1 (i.e. Linear quantization) but what do we expect for a-law, what for mu-law? From what I read from one of the linked sites, the following values are IBM specific and not a-law/mu-law in general (`$0101` IBM mu-law (custom), `$0102` = IBM a-law (custom)). I've seen `$14=06, $15=00` for a-law being used in the wild. So there may be other common values for that, who knows.